# After changing navigationbar background color , y position of self.view is changed

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

On viewwillAppear I am changing the navigationbar background color. I am trying to set a view with frame (0,53,width,height). On the first go it is showing proper and it's taking 53 after navigationbar's height but when I change the theme and come to that controller it's taking 53 from 0. So it's hiding behind the navigation bar.

I am writing following code in viewwillappear.

```
if(oldTheme)
{
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"bar.png"), for: .default)
}
else {
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"bar2.png"), for: .default)
}
```

Please advice.

THanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you change `backgroundColor` property you call `layoutSubviews` and eventually cause everything to layout again. If you set your view frame programmatically you should do that in in `layoutSubviews` of the view or in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` of a `viewController`